# Why am I getting alternating data from the Flight Cheapest Date Search endpoint?

Tags: amadeus

When sending GET requests to the Test API for [Flight Cheapest Date Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-cheapest-date-search/api-reference) with Postman, I seem to be getting two different result sets on repeated requests.

```
GET https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=ATL&destination=SFO
```

E.g., for a search for the connection ATL-SFO which is listed [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md), I'm getting, alternatingly, 404 errors ("no price result found") on one request and a full 390 KB list of results with the warning "maximum response size reached" on the next request.
Even for pairs that are supposedly not supported like LAX-SFO, I'm getting alternatingly 500-errors and a full, sorted list of flights.

Is this documented behavior and is there something I can do on my side to get consistent results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising the issue. We had an issue with one of the node used for this API. This has been fixed and should work properly now.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm still getting different results for every second request. ATL-SFO does not return 404 errors now but for the best price I'm getting 198, then 226.20, then 198 again ... With LAX-SFO the 500 errors for every second request are also still there.

Comment: I do not think this problem is fixed. I am getting no results in the production environment for BNA to TPA and MSP to MEM in the cheapest date endpoint, despite there being flights available and flight-offers returning results. I have submitted it to Amadeus support. It is very frustrating because it reflects poorly on my web application and my reputation.

Comment: @user12687708 I cannot reproduce this behavior. Can you please send the exact use case to reproduce at developers@amadeus.com.

Comment: @Steve Flight Inspiration Search and Flight Cheapest Date Search are built on a pre-computed cache, it means these 2 APIs do not offer the full coverage of all possible origin-destination pairs but only a subset. We have performed a cache migration last week to improve the data coverage, data quality, and response time of the API. In order to have a full data domain with live data you need to use the Flight Offers Search API.

Comment: @AnthonyRoux I'm getting consistent results now, i.e., no alternating between two sets. However, specifically for the connections I mentioned, ATL-SFO now returns a 500 error ("ORIGIN AND DESTINATION NOT ALLOWED FOR AMA4DEV EXTREME SEARCH REQUESTS ON ENVIRONMENT") whereas LAX-SFO gives results even though it is not listed in https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md. My only problem now is that I would like to know which connections work in the Test API without having to try but I'm guessing the list of supported connections will get updated at some point.

Comment: You are right, the data collection was not updated yet. It is the case now :) https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md

Comment: Is this broken again? https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=ATL&destination=SFO
{"errors":[{"status":404,"code":6003,"title":"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price result found"},{"status":404,"code":6003,"title":"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price results found for input combined criteria"}]}